# MySQL having 1 primary key with auto increment for 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, key, primary-key

I have 2 tables '**table1**' & '**table2**', both have column named '**id**' (*primary key*) and both have auto increment. The problem is how do I make the primary key viable for the both tables.

Example: 
I enter id '**100**' in '**table1**' and after that if I try to enter a new record in '**table2**' I would have '**101**' in '**table2**'

I thought 'foreign key' would do the job but it did the exactly opposite of what I need

Comment: Why do you need this? IDs for each table should be independent. If they're not, there's something wrong with your schema, they should actually be the same table.

Comment: can you post your database schema?

Comment: You don't need that. There doesn't exist a scenario where anyone would need such functionality. You might think you need it, but you don't. That's the cold truth, without even taking a look at your requirement or data model. Now, the cool part about StackOverflow is that you can present your problem and ask about possible solutions. Not for something you *think* is a solution. Classic XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, there's no way to do what you describe without resorting to extra queries or extra locking.

You can simulate it by creating a third table, into which you insert to generate new id's, then use LAST_INSERT_ID() to insert into either table1 or table2. See example in [How to have Unique IDs across two or more tables in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961580/how-to-have-unique-ids-across-two-or-more-tables-in-mysql)

Also see some discussion of this problem and solutions here at the popular MySQL Performance Blog: [Sharing an auto_increment value across multiple MySQL tables](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/04/sharing-an-auto_increment-value-across-multiple-mysql-tables/)

But I agree with the comment from @Barmar, this might be an indication of a bad design for a database. If you have a requirement to make the auto-increment PK unique across multiple tables, this may mean that the two tables should really be one table.