# Adding id from same source for two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, `Threads` and `Posts` and currently they both have `id` as auto-incremented integer which is primary key, so when a user adds a new thread, its `id` will be 1, then for a new post `id` will be 1 as well. And I want the id for that post to be 2, and for new post/thread 3 and so on.
I'm using Postgesql, thank you for any advice.

Comment: Don't do this.  Threads and posts are different entities.  Their primary keys should not be confused with each other.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correct, you want to avoid the id 1 for the first new post, correct? the easiest way to do it is to just delete the first line manually from the table post and since it is  auto-incremented integer it will not create 1

Comment: Not really. I want to have one auto-incrementing pull of id's for both threads and posts. So for the first entity (despite being a post or a thread) id will be 1, for second 2 and so on. It's like having one id column but for two tables.

Comment: It dose not sound correct (for the future) to have unique id across two tables but one way to do it is instead of auto-incremented you can check the last ID value of both tables and add ID+1 to the table you want or you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961580/how-to-have-unique-ids-across-two-or-more-tables-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to let the primary key be auto-incremented. In case, it's compulsory for your requirement, you can retrieve the maximum id of the other table, add 1 to it and insert this value in the id column of the current table, before adding any new row.
Code for retrieving the maximum id:

```
select max(id) from threads
```

Comment: id's are already auto-incrementing, but they are separate for threads and posts. It seems like your solution works only for adding posts, but when adding a thread I'll also have to check max id from posts AND threads, get it and increment. Just was wondering if there is any prebuilt way to do this in sql.

Comment: No, there isn't any inbuilt method to do so in sql. You have to implement the same logic for both threads as well as posts. I wrote threads' example because i assumed you'd figure out how to do it for posts using my example.