# How to use UUID

Tags: python, django, django-models, uuid

I am trying to get unique IDs for my Django objects.  In Django 1.8 they have the UUIDField.  I am unsure how to use this field in order to generate unique IDs for each object in my model.

Here is what I have for the UUIDField

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    unique_id = MyUUIDModel()
```

I can reproduce the id for the UUID model, but everytime I do I get the exact same id. For Example:

```
person = Person.objects.get(some_field = some_thing)
id = person.unique_id.id
```

id then gives me the same id every time.  What is wrong, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I'm not sure why you've created a UUID model. You can add the uuid field directly to the Person model.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
```

Each person should then have a unique id. If you wanted the uuid to be the primary key, you would do:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Your current code hasn't added a field to the person. It has created a `MyUUIDModel` instance when you do MyUUIDModel(), and saved it as a class attribute. It doesn't make sense to do that, the `MyUUIDModel` will be created each time the models.py loads. If you really wanted to use the MyUUIDModel, you could use a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey). Then each person would link to a different MyUUIDModel instance.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    unique_id = models.ForeignKey(MyUUIDModel, unique=True)
```

However, as I said earlier, the easiest approach is to add the UUID field directly to the person.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the class you created as a subclass when declaring your Person model like this:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class Person(MyUUIDModel):
  ...
```

This way Person becomes a subclass of MyUUIDModel and will inherit its id field definition.

Comment: this seems to capture the OP's intent, I think?

Comment: You should make `MyUUIDModel` abstract to avoid creating a table for it. If you don't, all classes that subclass `MyUUIDModel` will share a common table with their IDs. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Answer (score 13):

EDIT: Actually I was wrong. It's not possible yet to implement it as `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` as it has to inherit from `IntegerField`. Here's [the ticket in the django project](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32577) with feature request to make it possible. Once it's resolved I'll update my answer.

---

As of Django 3.2, if you want to use `uuid` as a pk for all your models on a project-wide level, you don't need a generic abstract model anymore. Just define [`DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/3.2/#customizing-type-of-auto-created-primary-keys) setting

default value

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
```

so something like this should work

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.UUIDField'
```

Or even better, create your own field.

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'project.common.models.CustomUUIDField'
```

Where you also define uuid type etc.

As seen in the docs, it can also be applied on an app level.

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'project.common.models.CustomUUIDField'
```

Comment: In 3.2, it says `Primary key 'django.db.models.UUIDField' referred by DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD must subclass AutoField.`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote in the ticket I added as an edit to this message a month ago.

Answer (score 11):

**You can directly add the `id` field as a [`UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.UUIDField) in the `Person` model**. There is no need for a separate `MyUUIDModel`.

I think you have confused it with the `MyUUIDModel` used in the [UUIDField example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.UUIDField) where the `id` is a `UUIDField`. You can just use the below code and it will use `UUIDs` for `id`.

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

To use UUID in Django for a **new model** see [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield).

However, if you want to use it for the **existing model** (with *unique=True*) having data corresponding to it, you will not be able to do it directly by the above documentation. It will create **migration errors**.
To do it without losing the data follow all the steps carefully of this [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields).

Answer (score 1):

in model import uuid:

```
import uuid
```

in class model use:

```
class Article(TimeStampedModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='articles', null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleCategory, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='portal_lobar_config')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='article_images/', null=True, blank=True)
    headline = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleTag, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=500, populate_from='title', unique_with='created__month', null=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
```