# Django: Unique order_reference

Tags: python, django, uuid

I have to create a unique order_reference field.

I read that I should use UUID for that. Can you recommend that? And is that here the right approach to it? (I found this snippet in another project)

```
uuid.UUID(bytes=base64.urlsafe_b64decode('%s==‘ % base64_uuid))
```

I don't understand what urlsafe_b64decode is doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528224/how-to-use-uuid-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `uuid` module for that:

```
import uuid as uuid_module

class MyModel(Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid_module.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using that in a model or form?

You can use `UUIDField` which is recommended usage. 
The database will not automagically create your `uuid` so you will have to pass a callable as

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):    
    order_reference = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) for further reference.