# Custom Django user model with UUID as the id field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am trying to extend a User model and add some fields and below is my approach:

```
Class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, blank=True, null=True)

class User_One(UserProfile):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ....
    ....

class User_Two(UserProfile):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ....
    ....
```

So basically there are two types of users `User_One` and `User_Two` and now whenever we save the two types of users into database the following happens

1. A `User` model record will be created with separate id of values 1,2,3 etc.,
2. A `User_One` model record will be created with id's 1,2,3
3. A `User_Two` model record will be created with id's 1,2,3

So for each every model record saving, Django or database was generating id's 1,2,3.

But I got a requirement that User model should generate a `uuid` for id field value in place of integers, was that possible?

I mean something like below

```
class User_Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Comment: Answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936182/using-a-uuid-as-a-primary-key-in-django-models-generic-relations-impact

Answer (score 4):

There are couple extra steps required to use uuid as a primary key:

1. Use `UUIDField` for your id field instead of `InegerField` because uuid isn't exactly an integer
2. Specify `primary_key=True` for that field

To get the custom user model, subclass it form `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` and specify `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings:

```
import uuid
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Then in your settings file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'youruserapp.UserProfile'
```

It's important to do that before you have any migrations (created a database) or this won't work.

Comment: can we generate this `uuid` in place of id value for standard `User` model id field ?

Comment: @shivakrishna Yes, absolutely. You need a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)

Comment: do we need to use any custom UserManager for the above user model  ?

Comment: awesome, so now we can inherit this `User_Profile` model and can create any number models like `User_one(User_Profile), User_two(User_Profile)` etc.,

Comment: @shivakrishna Yes, it should work.I don't know your exact requirements, you might want to use [proxy inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) if you want to keep it a single table in the database.

Comment: No, i want to create separate models for each class, ok now if we delete the `User_Profile` model, all the child classes(models) that inherited from this `User_Profile` model will also be deleted ?

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question specifically about inheritance if you end up facing issues with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144811/discussion-between-igonato-and-shiva-krishna).