# Mask URL in Django + React webApp

Tags: python, reactjs, django, url

I want to share a page with clients over mail which is something like this:

```
https://blabla.com/docket/2443
```

but if I do so they can access all other pages by just changing the docket no. i.e. `2443` in this case.
I tried to use `tiny-url` but it's of no use. Is there any way to mask the URL to solve the above problem?

Comment: use uuid instead of integer auto field for primary key

Comment: @VaibhavVishal please elaborate ?

Comment: in your modal you can add an id field as primary key and set it's default value to uuid.uuidv4. By default django uses auto field for primary key, so it goes like 1, 2, 3, 4 ..., but if you use uuid, the primary key will be unguessable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28469575/9321755

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to that problem.

1. If that endpoint requires a login and related to a **User**, you can add permissions to that endpoint which makes it only accessible for the user(s) who are related to it.
2. If it is a public URL, You can make the `id` more sophisticated than an integer, you can make the id field a `UUIDField`, which makes it really hard to guess any other dockets ids.

Comment: I have already created 2000+ dockets so if i add an `UUID` field then how do i fill all of them ?

Comment: `id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)`, now run `python manage.py makemigrations`, then `python manage.py migrate`, it will run the default value for the previously created records. You can test it locally to make sure it is not going to harm your data.

Comment: I just ran the migrations and it says `  - Remove field id from allotment
    - Add field uid to allotment`  I have used id multiple times in my code. Can we add `UUID` without deleting the `id`

Comment: `id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)`, this should do, you have to specify that this field is a `primary_key`

Comment: It was True in the above code.. it tries to remove the `id