# Django: How to make Id unique between 2 different model classes

Tags: python, django

Im working on a problem that requires 2 different models to have unique Ids. So that an instance of ModelA should never have the same id as a ModelB instance.

For example, What would be the Django way of making sure these two model types wont have overlapping Ids?

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class OnlineCustomer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**Edit 1:**

Here is an example of something that I've done that works, but does not feel correct. Should I be inheriting from a concrete base class?

```
class UniqueID(models.Model):
    pass


def create_unique_id():
    try:
        UniqueID = UniqueID.objects.create()
    except:
        # This try except is here to allow migration to pass since Customers need access to this function during migration
        # This should never happen
        return 0
    return UniqueID.id

class Customer(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=create_unique_id)

class OnlineCustomer(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=create_unique_id)
```

Comment: Do you have any code you tried to present? It is nice to show what you've tried and what you've got so people can start working on solutions, if it is the case.
Anyway: do you have constructors for these models? It may be nice to provide more context on the classes. With a constructor you could query to get used `ids` from other models before creating a new entry.

Comment: Matheus see Edit 1

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

Comment: For a UUID field, should I be concerned about performance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936182/using-a-uuid-as-a-primary-key-in-django-models-generic-relations-impact#:~:text=However%2C%20nothing%20requires%20the%20UUID,UUID%20as%20your%20external%20identifier.

Comment: Depends on the specifications you have. As per the answer the question you linked, you can also use another value as the primary key, and still keep the unique id with `UUIDField`, having less effect on performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Vishal Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7865368/vishal-singh) commented, the `UUIDField` class from Django's `Model` can be used to create

> A field for storing universally unique identifiers.

As mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield).

Usage could be as following:

```py
import uuid
from django.db import models


class Customer(models.Model):
    id_ = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class OnlineCustomer(models.Model):
    id_ = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```