# changing primary key from username to uuid on POSTGREQL gives: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "username" is in a primary key

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm, django-migrations

I have a postgresql database and I am making a migration to switch my pk from username to uuid.

I already made a data migration file where I add a uuid to every row in my model
it worked fine on sqlite but when I was testing it on postgresql I got an error.

The error was "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "username" is in a primary key"

I am not sure where to begin to debug this thing. Here is the model, data migration, migration, and stack trace of the error:

```py
# models.py
class UserInformation(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

```py
# data migration 42
import uuid

from django.db import migrations


def set_uuid_for_all_user_information(apps, schema_editor):
    UserInformation = apps.get_model('accounts', 'UserInformation')

    for userInformation_user in UserInformation.objects.all():
        userInformation_user.uuid = uuid.uuid4().hex
        userInformation_user.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0041_auto_20211227_2113'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(set_uuid_for_all_user_information),
    ]
```

```py
# migration 43 (this is where the postgresqsl error occurs) trying to change pk from username to uuid

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import uuid


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('accounts', '0042_auto_20211229_2319'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='userinformation',
            name='user',
            field=models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='auth.user'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='userinformation',
            name='username',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True, unique=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='userinformation',
            name='uuid',
            field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False),
        ),
    ]
```

when running python manage.py migrate, I get this error:

```sh
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, legal, sessions, sites, socialaccount
Running migrations:
  Applying accounts.0043_auto_20211229_2321...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTableDefinition: column "username" is in a primary key


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..\python\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 52, in <module>
    run_command()
  File "C:\..\python\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 46, in run_command
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "C:\..\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 207, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\..\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\..\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\..\my_site\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 244, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 608, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema.py", line 196, in _alter_field
    super()._alter_field(
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 765, in _alter_field
    self.execute(
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "username" is in a primary key
```

I was thinking of solving this with raw SQL in the database, but I wasn't sure if that would cause further problems or not. I would much rather fix it with a django fix instead of raw sql

Comment: It looks like you're changing from numerical IDs to UUID for HIPAA reasons? Using the UUID is only necessary if you're making the information public somehow, like through an API. You don't need to only have a UUID in the database. Keep the existing `id` field as the pk, and then make sure your API endpoints are only returning the UUID field, not the `id` field.

Answer (score 0):

Hi **AugustusCaesar**,

When you remove UUID that time there UUID already migrated files present in migrations folder. So in a simple way, you on the local server first take backup then drop this database...

for backup.
pg_dumpall -U postgres > c:\pgbackup\all.sql

1. sudo su postgres
2. drop database database_name
3. psql livedx_qa < /home/Documents/database_name.sql <- again dump DB

python3 manage.py makemigrations

python3 manage.py migrate

I also face this issue you can use this solution. You can't delete manually migrations files this is not the right way so !!!!!

**Thank You!!!**

Comment: I have not tried this yet, but even if it works in development it would be very scary and dangerous in production to drop a database and try to restore it. Is there not another way?

Comment: A UUID primary key will cause problems not only with generic relations, but with efficiency in general: every foreign key will be significantly more expensive—both to store, and to join on—than a machine word.

However, nothing requires the UUID to be the primary key: just make it a secondary key, by supplementing your model with a uuid field with unique=True. Use the implicit primary key as normal (internal to your system), and use the UUID as your external identifier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3944247/14471664 please try this one !! I asked with my senior so he gave me this link So !!!