# How can I encrypt <int:pk> inside my URLs?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I think it's a dumb question, but I can't solve this problem anyway. I'm building a simple card game with chatrooms in Django. When a mod creates a room, to enter this room you need to use the following URL:

```
cardgame/room/<int:pk>
```

where inside of `<int: pk>` is replaced by the `id` of the room created. My problem is that some random user could enter the room of `id=x` just using a link like `cardgame/room/x` without being invited. I wanted to encrypt the id number whenever a room is created, just like when you create a Google meet call but I dont know how to this using Django/Python.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a UUIDField instead? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of
[Using a UUID as a primary key...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936182/using-a-uuid-as-a-primary-key-in-django-models-generic-relations-impact)

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

This changes the default behaviour of django models, which are creating `id` as an `AutoField`. Either you can do this or add an additional uuid field

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a UUID field to your model to create a universally unique identifiers and then using that as the path variable instead?

Something like this:

```py
class Room(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
```